# checking of dynamically created forms on Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, callback

I need to create any number of instances of Form1 (MDI) which is dynamically created

```
class procedure TForm1.ShowForm;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
begin
  Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);

  Form1.Show;
end;
```

On Close:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin   
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

that Form has a button who calls Form2. 
Form2 process some stuff, shows the progress and at the end executes a callback function passed on its creation:

callback on Form1:

```
procedure TForm1.MyCallback(icont_process: Integer);
begin
  Self.LabelResult.Caption := IntToStr(icont_process)+' processed itens.');
end;
```

creation of Form2:

```
class procedure TForm2.ShowForm(AMyCallback: TMyCallback);
var
  Form2: TForm2;
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);

  with Form2 do
  begin
    FMyCallback := AMyCallback;

    Show;
  end;
end;
```

the problem occurrs on the Callback...

How can I check if the instance of Form1 of which the result should be returned is still valid?
If I close Form1, Form2 should not execute the Callback... any idea on how should I check that?

Comment: Something like: When Form1 calls TForm2.ShowForm() save a reference to the created Form2 (change class procedure to class function and return the ref of Form2. Declare a procedure "ShutDown" in Form2, which Form1 can call (with the ref it has). Form2 stops its task and frees itself in "ShutDown". Form1 deletes the Form2 ref if and when Form2 exits normally via the callback.

Comment: thank you @TomBrunberg, I believe that the Remy Lebeu's aswer also made the same approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Simply don't let `Form1` close while its associated `Form2` is still open.  For instance, use `Form2.ShowModal()` instead of `Form2.Show()`.
2. If you must allow `Form2` to outlive `Form1`, then make `Form1` hold a reference to its associated `Form2`, and then clear the callback pointer when `Form1` is closed.

   ```
   private
     FForm2: TForm2;

   procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   begin   
     if FForm2 <> nil then
       FForm2.FMyCallback := nil;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
   begin   
     Action := caFree;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     if FForm2 = nil then
     begin
       FForm2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
       FForm2.FMyCallback := MyCallback;
       FForm2.OnDestroy := Form2Destroyed;
     end;
     FForm2.Show;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.Form2Destroyed(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     FForm2 := nil;
   end;
   ```